# Warning shown when asking questions on desktop site but not when asked with the app

Tags: bug, questions, android-app

I was asking questions on my Android phone for some time and when I went to ask a question from the web I got this error:

> You have a history of asking low quality questions. Please put more thought, time, and effort into your questions. To help you do this, the number of questions you may ask per week is currently limited. For more information, visit the Help Center.

But when I ask using my Android phone it submits successfully.

I was first using an account on which I have been banned for asking questions so I deleted that account and started a new one. From the new one I had gained 20 rep then I asked a stupid question that took half my rep, **then** I started answering questions (mostly through my phone).

Comment: When you submit from the web are you using a shared IP address? college/work etc.

Comment: Home WiFi network

Comment: Your'e able to *submit* questions, but you're not seeing that warning message on mobile?

Comment: Both phone and web are used at home WiFi network

Comment: So the bug is that android should have blocked you as well?

Comment: @Makoto no I'm not getting any error at all

Comment: I wouldn't call it an error.  I'd consider that the message isn't being sent through the API, which does sound like a bug.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that you use more than one user account.   One on your phone, another on "web" (whatever that means).  Getting blocked on one but not the other is a bug, not one that's going to be fixed any time soon.  SO users very rarely complain about that, they tend to like being able to bypass a question ban.

Comment: @HansPassant:  No, that doesn't make sense.  You use the same account on mobile as you do the website.  They're also not banned; they're being *warned*.  I'm not so sure that what you're suggesting makes sense in this scenario.

Comment: @Makoto That is an error, not a warning. If we're not respecting this limit in mobile apps, that's a bug.

Comment: Alright @AnnaLear, that makes sense.  I wasn't sure if it was an error or warning message, since it does convey some sort of warning. I've not encountered it before, so I couldn't be sure.

Comment: @Hans Passant I use same account on both web and Mobile

Comment: It probably means you haven't reached your limit yet. The message is only a warning that the number of questions you can ask is limited. I don't know how limited. You could have a hundred questions per week.

Comment: I will add a more info edit

Comment: So you indeed used more than one account.  You are of course not supposed to bypass a question ban like that.  What happens next is quite unpredictable, be prepared to run when the feds bust through the front door.

Comment: @jakekimds: When it says "limited" it means *limited*. [Single digits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide). (Given that asking the same sort of questions at the same rate will result in q-ban within days....)